# metadata_startup_script not running when Terraform is launch from Azure Pipelin

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a Terraform code that is running perfectly fine on my local computer, the issue happens ONLY when I run it from an Azure Pipeline.

My TF code creates several GCP VM Instances using google_compute_instance, each instace use the metadata and metadata_startup_script to upload the public key and run an initial script respectively, but for some unknown reason ONLY the metadata_startup_script is NOT running when TF is launch from an Azure Pipine, everything else runs fine.

The TF Plan recognizes the initial-script content (vars and values as well) and mention it will be apply, but at the end is being skip during the TF Apply phase.
I have tried to using it on different ways (as int he code below) but none of the options is executed.

```
    data "template_file" "admin" {
      template = file("initial-setup.sh")
      vars = {
        password = "${random_password.admin_password.result}"
        prefix = "${var.prefix}"
      }
    }

Call inside google_compute_instance --->
    metadata_startup_script = "${data.template_file.admin.rendered}"
    metadata_startup_script = file("initial-setup.sh")
    metadata_startup_script = "useradd -m -s /bin/bash 'admin';echo 'admin:password@54w21@123@@' | chpasswd"
```

None of the options above run when TF is launch from an Azure Pipeline, only from local computer. It is possible to force this? or could be an issue with the agent pool missing something ?

**Update 1**: I found that the script content is attached to the VM at the custom metadata section (gcp portal), is it possible to query the logs on the gcp portal and find something related to it?

Comment: Your problem is this line: `file("C:/Program Files/Terraform/initial-setup.sh`. The pipeline cannot access files on your local machine. Copy the file to Google Cloud Storage, grant the service account or principal permission to read storage, and specify that path instead.

Comment: Warning: Why are you developing in `C:/Program Files"? That means you have administrator rights. Both are very dangerous.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have edited that part to avoid misunderstanding, I copied the code from the local computer instead of the azure repo. The script is actually on the same level that TF, so basically everything is located on --> $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/appv5/Terraform, but even so, that instruction is not being executed during TF Apply, although is being recognized during TF Plan.gDirectory)/appv5/Terraform

Answer (score 0):

From your Terraform code, you are using the bash file on your local machine: `C:/Program Files/Terraform/initial-setup.sh`.

When you run the terraform script on your local machine, the file can be read directly on the target path.

But when you using the Azure Pipeline to run the Terraform script, the file will not be checked out to the path `C:/Program Files/`.

To solve this issue, you can add the `initial-setup.sh` file to the same repo of the terraform.

When you run the Pipeline, the file will be checked out to the Source Folder: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)`. However, since terraform cannot read Pipeline variables directly, you need to specify a hard-coded path. The following is a sample

Microsoft-hosted windows Agent: `D:\a\1\s\xxx\initial-setup.sh`

Microsoft-hosted Ubuntu Agent: `/home/vsts/work/1/s/xxx/initial-setup.sh`

Microsoft-hosted MacOs Agent: `/Users/runner/work/1/s/xx/initial-setup.sh`

You can run the script: `echo "$(build.sourcesdirectory)"` to confirm the repo checkout path.

Comment: I have edited that part to avoid misunderstanding, I copied the code from the local computer instead of the azure repo. The script is actually on the same level that TF, so basically everything is located on --> $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/appv5/Terraform, but even so, that instruction is not being executed during TF Apply, although is being recognized during TF Plan.

Comment: @GTGabaaron What kind of  agent are you using? And can you check if the Azure Pipeline is using the same version as Local machine.

Comment: I'm using a self-hosted agent and the TF versions are different. That being said, I found something, I'm new to GCP  and I was unaware of the custom metadata section within each VM, I found that the startup-script content is listed there as well, is it possible to use google logs to find something related to why the script is not being executed ?

Answer (score 0):

So, after quite some time I found the answer to my issue, the root cause was basically a compatibility issue between the azure repo, the windows agent pool and the linux bash script. You can basically solve this by using a linux agent pool or adding a gitattribute file to treat the bash file, always a linux files, that way the \r character won't be added to some lines.

Comment: Glad to know that you have found the solution to solve the issue. You can accept this answer. This will be helpful to other users who has the same issue.